# Json-server responds Error 404 not found Post Method using React js and Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, json-server

i get a error in my xhr network tab saying 'cannot POST /streams',i want to make a post request using axios and i have setup 'json-server',i have added db.json file and edited the script tag to

```
"scripts": {"start": "json-server -p 3001 -w db.json"},
```

and i am dispatching an action,in that action i have written post method

```
export const add_Stream = (formValues) => async (dispatch) => {
 Streams.post("/streams", formValues);
};
```

Here is my db.json file data

```
{
    "streams":[]
}
```

and i have created base url

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseUrl: "http://localhost:3001",
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this happens because of your axios baseUrl params.
Try this.
export default axios.create({
baseURL: "localhost:3001",
});

Comment: first i tried  adding export default axios.create({ baseURL: "localhost:3001", }) it gave me error '(failed)net::ERR_FAILED,and Replaced with export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:3001",
}); and it worked.

Comment: Maybe the problem is just wrong key.

axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:3001",
}); Can you try this ?

Comment: the mistake in my code was 'baseUrl'  instead it should be baseURL.

Comment: it only works if add  `export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:3001",
});`

Comment: Actually in this comment i write like this but comment was changed :D.  I hope i helped. At least the problem is solved.